# Android setText / R.string / values

Tags: android, textview, settext

I am having trouble with setting text in a text view with format and multiple values.

```
holder.car.setText(R.string.mycar + lm.getCarName() + R.string.year + lm.getYear());
```

this is giving me " 2143545 Camero 2143213 1977 "

I have tried few other "solutions" from the web

```
holder.car.setText(getString(R.string.mycar) + lm.getCarName() + getString(R.string.year) + lm.getYear());  << not work, getString undefine>>
```

I even tried `String.valueOf(R.string.mycar);  getResources().getText(R.String.mycar)`, still it didn't work.

It would be great if someone can help me, thanks

Comment: what does "still not work" means? What do you expect?

Comment: It's because `R.string.mycar` is an `int` that refers to a resource. It's not the actual resource. @user1417127 's answer looks good. It fetches the actual string resource for you

Comment: use context.getResources.getString(R.string.xyx).

Answer (score 26):

Try this

`holder.car.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.mycar));`

Answer (score 14):

I think you're trying to use parameters in your string.

Try this:

```
<string name="mycar">Car: %1$s Year: %2$s</string>

String mycar = getString(R.string.mycar);
mycar = String.format(mycar, lm.getCarName(), lm.getYear());
```

You should get:

Car: Camaro Year: 1977

Answer (score 6):

If you want to set your textview just a string from your string.xml file,

```
mytextview.setText(R.String.mycar);
```

If you want to set your textview with combination of some strings or integers, (better than first way)

```
int number=5;

mytextview.setText(getResources().getString(R.String.mycar) + " " +number + " " + getResources().getString(R.String.mysecondcar));
```

Comment: How to deal with the Android Studio warning: "Do no concanate text displayed with setText. Use Resource string with place holders" ?

Answer (score 4):

R.string.mycar and R.string.year are only IDs for resources. For this reason you get the numbers (IDs are numeric).

To get string from resources you need to use this construction:

```
String myCar = getResources().getString(R.string.mycar);
```

and now the myCar variable holds the string you put in strings.xml file under the mycar name.

the method getResources() belongs to Context. If you run your code outside an Activity, use the context instance to get the string, like this:

```
String myCar = context.getResources().getString(R.string.mycar);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this. If you're fetching string in class without extending `Activity` Get using your `Context`

```
holder.car.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.mycar));
```

If you're extending `Activity`

```
holder.car.setText(yourActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.mycar));
```

Hope this helps you..

Comment: instead of `context` can we write `getActivit()` ? are there any problem

Comment: @mehmet It depends on your requirement. Read the [document here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity())

Answer (score 2):

You have to retrieve your resources first, and the call the medthod getString(int), not getText, has you have put.

So, it should be:

```
getResources().getString(R.String.mycar);
```

Answer (score 0):

The R class contains kind of pointers to your ressources, so you can not directly use them, use getResources().getString(), as others say.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
context.getText(R.string.mycar);
```

just.
The `context` is the activity that is passed to the adapter.
It works for me.